# Is there a system-wide equalizer for PulseAudio or ALSA?

Tags: sound, system, equalizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any Sound enhancers/equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer)

I often want to tweak the sound quality, but have found no other way than to install plugins for each piece of software. Unfortunately this is not available for all the apps I use, e.g. Spotify.

Is there a way to install a system-wide equalizer on Ubuntu?