# How can I enable the pulseaudio equalizer?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, equalizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any Sound enhancers/equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer)

Pulseaudio version 1.0 includes its own equalizer [(Release Notes)](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Notes/1.0), but it seems that it's disabled in Ubuntu 12.04 (https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/932834). I know of the discontinued pulseaudio-equalizer app from [webupd8.com](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/09/download-pulseaudio-system-wide.html), but it doesn't work anymore in Precise.

How can I enable pulseaudio's own system-wide equalizer?

Comment: did you read the rest of the bug report? In src/Makefile.am is this code:

if HAVE_DBUS
if HAVE_FFTW
modlibexec_LTLIBRARIES += \
  module-equalizer-sink.la
bin_SCRIPTS += utils/qpaeq
endif
endif

So for equalizer module is needed package fftw-dev. Please add needed fftw packages to pulseaudio build depends for equalizer support.