# Graphical sound equalizer (EQ) for Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: sound, alsa, equalizer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any Sound enhancers/equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer)

Is there a graphical sound equalizer for Ubuntu 12.04?

If not, is there a tentative schedule/website where I can know of any developments?

Thanks.