# How to add a system wide equalizer in Ubuntu 12?

Tags: 12.04, sound

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there any Sound enhancers/equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer)

I found many posts about 'pulseaudio-equalizer' but it doesn't seem to work anymore. I tried to install it with apt-get.

Anyone else with sound configuration problems in Ubuntu 12?

My sound comes out with too much bass. I'm sure it's not a problem in my headphones or anything else. It's the sound configuration, which is not possible to change with the default tools.

alsamixer helped me to disable 'front mi'. I don't know what that is, but when I muted it, all the noise was removed. So now all I need to do is turn down the bass.

Comment: @fossfreedom I already saw that post, but it's too old. Where can I see that package for 12.04?

Comment: look at the ppa:nilarimogard/webupd8 answer - if you look on launchpad in that PPA there appears to be a 12.04 pulseaudio equalizer package.

Comment: @fossfreedom Ok thanks, it worked. But everything is so buggy..  I fixed the bass with the equalizer, but now sound is too low, and I can't turn it higher. Also, flash doesn't care about the equalizer, seems like it uses a different driver or something. And sometimes the volume control stops working. This is frustrating.