# Can't install the X-Fi driver from the Creative site

Tags: drivers, sound

Because I can't adjust the bass/treble levels through alsamixer I tried installing the drivers for my X-Fi Titanium Pro card from the creative website.

The Readme file tells me to just execute `make` and `make install` as root in the directory but when I do that I get the following error:

```
The file or directory does not exist:
#include sound/driver.h>
^
compilation terminated.
```

That happens after the make command.

I have installed the make essentials and the generic headers.

Comment: Same issue here. Wish someone knew a fix to the issue. This is what I get: ..."fatal error: sound/driver.h: No such file or directory #include <sound/driver.h> ^
compilation terminated. "

Answer (score 1):

You tried installing the driver release below? Give it up.

The vendor doesn't support it, the community doesn't either and it's horribly outdated. X-Fi support on Linux is a very long and sad story. Be happy with the functionality you get from the community supported drivers or buy another card/device.

Usually there are no bass controls implemented at driver level. **Use an equalizer instead.** See answers to the following question: [Is there any Sound enhancers/equalizer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer)

---

From the creative support website:

> Driver
>
> Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi and X-Fi Titanium Series Linux 32-bit /
>   64-bit Driver Source Release
>
> File size: 68,8 KB [Download](http://support.creative.com/downloads/download.aspx?nDownloadId=10792)
>
> *Release date: **6 Nov 08***
>
> File name: XFiDrv_Linux_Public_US_1.00.tar.gz
>
> This download is a source release driver providing Linux® 32-bit /
>   64-bit OS support for Creative Sound Blaster® X-Fi™ and X-Fi Titanium
>   series of audio devices. For more details, read the rest of this web
>   release note.
>
> Take note of the following:
>
> - **THIS IS AN UNSUPPORTED DRIVER**. There is no technical support for this driver.
> - We recommend that only experienced users install this driver. Do not install this driver on a system used to perform critical tasks.
>
> This download is intended for the following audio devices only:
>
> - Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Titanium Fatal1ty® Champion Series
> - Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Titanium Fatal1ty Professional Series
> - Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Titanium Professional Audio
> - Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Titanium
> - Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Elite Pro
> - Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Platinum
> - Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi Fatal1ty
> - Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi XtremeGamer
> - Creative Sound Blaster X-Fi XtremeMusic
>
> Current release features:
>
> - ALSA PCM Playback
> - ALSA Record
> - ALSA Mixer
>
> Known issues:
>
> - External I/O modules are not supported in this driver release.
> - Applications from the Installation CD of your Sound Blaster audio device will not work with this driver.
>
> Requirements:
>
> - Linux x86 / x86_64 OS
> - Creative Sound Blaster audio devices listed above
>
> Notes:
>
> - To install the driver, do the following:
>
>   1. Download the tarball package onto your local hard disk.
>   2. Un-tarball the downloaded package to unpack its contents.
>   3. Read the README file and follow the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

you know, header files sometimes s need to install before do anything while installing other software. 
First you need to find your sound driver installed on you computer and its name, for example, "ALSA". Then try to find "ALSA-dev" or something like that ends with -dev. So, you should install this packages named, something-dev to have proper .h file in your driver folder.
Regards.

Comment: "**THIS IS AN UNSUPPORTED DRIVER.**"