# Is there any Sound Equalizer for Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: sound, 17.04, plugins, equalizer

I'm really new in Ubuntu. I never used it before. Any time I face any kind of problem of needing I hit google bar and I get solution from askubuntu.com.

**But this time I failed to find solution of equalizer for Ubuntu 17.04**

Isn't there any?? :(

Comment: Check [THIS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer) out.

Comment: yes, I already checked that and as the guy said. installed correctly but i can't find the program.

Comment: I have did all [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer) and there after I installed everything in the post says but I couldn't find any graphic equalizer from my dash! please help guys!