# can't find Pulse-Equalizer program

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, 17.04, equalizer

my ubuntu has upgraded from 16.04 to 17.04. I didn't had pulse-equalizer before. I asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/951754/is-there-any-sound-equalizer-for-ubuntu-17-04) and I found a solution to installing the program from this [link](https://packages.ubuntu.com/zesty/pulseaudio-equalizer). All installed correctly and found it on synaptic package manager and working properly, I mean no error but I couldn't find any program named 'Pulse Equalizer' from my dash.
I'm pretty novice on ubuntu.
Help me to get out guys! :|

```
pulseaudio-equalizer: 
   Installed: 1:10.0-1ubuntu2 
   Candidate: 1:10.0-1ubuntu2 
   Version table: 
*** 1:10.0-1ubuntu2 500 
     500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages 
     500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages  
     100 /var/lib/dpkg/status 2.7.0.2-5~webupd8~xenial0 500 
     500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages 
     500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is called `pulseaudio-equalizer`.  To make sure you really installed it, you can type the command

`apt-cache policy pulseaudio-equalizer`

On my 14.04 system this returns

```
pulseaudio-equalizer:
  Installed: 2.7.0.2-4~webupd8~1
  Candidate: 2.7.0.2-4~webupd8~1
  Version table:
 *** 2.7.0.2-4~webupd8~1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Note that I installed it from a ppa.

Once installed, it shows up in the dash as expected.

[image]

I suspect you did not install it successfully.

Comment: `pulseaudio-equalizer:
  Installed: 1:10.0-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 1:10.0-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 1:10.0-1ubuntu2 500
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages
        500 http://cz.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.7.0.2-5~webupd8~xenial0 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu zesty/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu zesty/main i386 Packages`

Comment: I edited your question to include this information, but some of it looks funny, as if you left some information out, and included some extra numbers.  You should edit your question to fix this stuff I pasted in, and include everything.

Comment: as I said I'm pretty novice in here!

now, how can I have that bloody equalizer? would you help me please? :|

Answer (score 0):

On my 17.10 system the equalizer program is also not showing up in the dash. To open the equalizer i used [these steps](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#Equalizer).

First load the modules:

```
pactl load-module module-equalizer-sink
pactl load-module module-dbus-protocol
```

And then open the equalizer:

```
qpaeq
```