# Filter high-pitched sound on live audio

Tags: alsa, media, frequency

I am running Ubuntu 18.04

Sometimes, I'll play a media file and it would have been encoded badly and there will be a very high-pitched whine in the background.

Is it possible to block sound from being played above a certain frequency?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/72679/is-there-any-sound-enhancers-equalizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a method of doing this using [PulseEffects](https://launchpad.net/pulseeffects).

1. Install it
   `sudo apt install pulseeffects`
2. Open it, select the speaker Icon in the top-left.
3. Click onto Applications, this is where you enable the PulseEffects modification for the sound made by specific applications.
4. On the left, open Filter and click the tick-box next to it. On some versions this might be called Low-Pass Filter.
5. Set the mode to 12dB/oct Lowpass, Frequency to 8000Hz, Resonance -3.0dB, Inertia 20.00ms.
   [image: The filter settings being shown.]

A pass filter, allows frequencies through within the selected range. A low-pass allows low frequencies, a high-pass allows high frequencies.

I find this works decently, the audio is not distorted by a huge amount but the high pitch sequel is gone completely, I find it an improved situation at least. Adjust the Frequency to change the cut-off point of frequencies filtered out, which may help reduce distortion.