# An equalizer with presets

Tags: sound

I'm looking for for a basic system wide equalizer with some pre-loaded presets. I've found several equalizers when searching the web, but all seem to be from PPA's, require some extensive tweaking to set up or their support seems to have been dropped.
This really surprised me, as I'd thought this is a basic functionality for any OS.
This makes me think I'm overlooking something obvious.

The reason for my need of a system wide equalizer with presets is that my laptop speakers seem to produce pretty lackluster quality on Ubuntu, especially compared to Windows. The sound appears to be 'hollow' or just not very rich, whichever way you want to describe it. At first i thought just one of the 2 speakers were producing sound because of said quality, but it appears they are both working properly.
I'm not well versed in the manual tweaks I need to do for equalizers that come without presets, so I'm looking for one that just works out of the box after installing.

Again, I might be missing something very obvious, as I'm still quite new to Linux as a whole, so please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has been answered a couple of times before, dessert has a good summary of all the options available: 
https://askubuntu.com/a/951207/351726

You should want to try `PulseAudio Equalizer` as long as you don't use any JACK software.

However, you mention having a "hollow" sound in Ubuntu compared to Windows. This shouldn't be the case. In general, the sound quality should be nearly indistinguishable between both systems.

Now, it's difficult to find out what the cause for this could be. Are you possibly used to an EQ that you have set up on Windows? Sometimes the soundcard drivers have automatic EQs that are activated without notifying you while you get the direct output in Ubuntu.

There's a possiblity that your output volume levels are set too high, make sure to check them and if they're close to or beyond 100%, turn them down a bit and listen again if anything changes.

Anything else might be a specific hardware issue.